# Мусор в буфере при эхо-запросе на плату stm nucleo, код на Си

Tags: c, embedded, stm32

Работаю с платой STM NUCLEO. Наладил общение между ноутбуком с ОС Линукс и платой по последовательному интерфейсу UART.
С ноутбука отправляем тестовое сообщение:

```
write( hSerial, "check\n\r", 7 );
```

и запускаем тред, который слушает порт и пишет в терминал:

```
void* thread2(void *v) 
{
   char chArrBuf[256];
   char chArrBuf2[256];
   int n;

   memset (&chArrBuf, '\0', sizeof(chArrBuf));
   while (1) {    
     n = read(hSerial, &chArrBuf, 1); 

     if (n > 0) printf("%s", chArrBuf);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Пользуюсь System Workbench и HAL библиотекой:

```
HAL_UART_Transmit(&hUART2, "EVENT:JOY_DOWN\r\n", 16, 0xFFFF);
```

(например, такое сообщение при движении джойстика вниз).

При попытке чтения сообщения с ноутбука в буфер попадает множество странных и иногда нечитаемых в терминале символов. Следующий код:

```
    i = 0;
    oRecvStatus = HAL_UART_Receive(&hUART2, chArr, 50, 100);
    if (oRecvStatus == HAL_OK) {
        while ((chArr[i] != "\n") && (chArr[i-1] != "\r")) {
            Buffer[i] = chArr[i];
            i++;
        }
        Buffer[i+1] = "\n";
    } 
    HAL_UART_Transmit(&hUART2, Buffer, strlen(Buffer), 0xFFFF);
```

В терминал на ноутбуке выводит " ^^J^JJ^^^Jcheck ", после нескольких последовательных выводов сообщения с платы в терминал оно меняется на что-то типа "^ck^JJ^^^JJJeck
J^^"

В силу недостатка опыта такой разработки не могу понять в чём проблема и как получить сообщение с ноутбука в чистом виде на плату для обработки и последующего парсинга.

Заранее спасибо за советы.

Comment: Проверьте параметры порта (скорость, кол-во стоп бит, контроль четности).

Answer (score 0):

Здесь я вижу несколько ошибок.

1. Первое сообщение `check` вы отправляете с последовательностью символов `\n\r`, а в коде приемника читаете, пока не встретите последовательность символов `\r\n`. Ее в этом сообщении нет.
2. Переменная Buffer, судя по ее использованию, является массивом символов. Вы же, после выхода из цикла чтения, пытаетесь записать в элемент `[i+1]` значение константного указателя на строку `"\n"`. Это неверно и приведет к неопределенному поведению. Если вы хотите записать туда символ, следует использовать `'\n'`.
3. Также следует проверить: baudrate COM-порта, парность, размер октета и количество стоп-битов. Но, судя по выводу, COM-порт принимает символы, но неверно их обрабатывает.